# "$\ell^\infty(T)$ is separable if and only if $T$ is countable" -- this is not correct, is it?

Tags: functional-analysis, empirical-processes

I am reading these notes https://mkosorok.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/14747/2017/07/lecture06.pdf on empirical processes. I am confused by the statement on slide 38:

> Note that $\ell^\infty(T)$ is separable if and only if $T$ is countable.

That is not true, is it? The notes define $\ell^\infty(T)$ as the space of all real-valued functions $f:T\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $\Vert f\Vert_T := \sup_{t\in T}\vert f(t)\vert < \infty$. Consider $T=\mathbb N$, which is countable. There are many posts here on MathSE discussing the fact that $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ is *not* separable. The notes discuss advanced results from functional analysis - I can't believe such a basic result would be misstated... or am I missing something here?

Comment: It is false  and you are right about the case $T=\mathbb N$ In fact, countable should be replaced by finite.

Comment: Of course this depends on the meaning of the notation $\ell^\infty(T)$; and the topoogy on it which is supposed to be separable.  Are these things covered in the notes?  Also note: **slides** are  not intended to be read alone; they are intended to accompany a lecture.  So we cannot tell what the lecurer said at this point!

Comment: Thank you for confirming my guess, geetha290krm. GEdgar: true, but unfortunately, this is all I have. The topology on $\ell^\infty(T)$ is the topology generated by the metric $d(x,y) = \Vert x - y\Vert_T$ (this is mentioned on the same slide). So there may still be a rare chance that it's correct (assuming a particular topology). But given the comment of geetha290krm, I now suppose that it's simply a typo: countable instead of finite

Comment: The space $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ is separable in the weak-\* topology (as the dual of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$), but in that case the result is also incorrect as $\ell^\infty(X)$ is also weak-\* separable for $|X| \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$.